# How to fix embedded code in richeditor - octobercms

Tags: php, octobercms, octobercms-backend

I'm using OctoberCMS RichEditor to create more dynamic texts.
The problem is that the text editor (rich editor) is not working the way it should when I click on "insert video" and I choose the "code" option and put the "HTML" and click the "insert" button nothing happens.

I'm putting down a link showing an embedded that I'm trying to do but nothing happens.

Print:

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Froala Editor is testing embedded code to check if it is **iframe** tag. If you want to insert **p** tag you should probably change editor to code view.

Check this https://github.com/froala/wysiwyg-editor/issues/1580